How to get http client to handle response for http method delete and body
.NET is not happy with DELETE requests that use body content. With the API I'm integrating with, the request looked like it was being sent but the response always timed out. This occurred both with WebClient and HttpClient. The API developers see the request on their end and respond with 200 but HttpClient doesn't get the response and timesout. Their API def works because I've hit it with postman and other request tools.
I tried adding various request/response headers. Using both HttpClient and WebRequest directly. I would expect any response from the API.
DeleteWithPostAsync(string url, string json)
{
   HttpRequestMessage request = new 
   HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, url)
   {
    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, 
    "application/json"),
     
   };

 var result = await 
 client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
 var response = await 
 result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
 return response;
}


RFC 9110 states "A client SHOULD NOT generate content in a DELETE request". However, there is nothing in .NET that prevents this, so if it's not working for you you're doing something wrong. Since you haven't shown us any of your code we can't guess what that might be.

Apologies, I added the code. I've also tried the override header, "X-HTTP-Method-Override","POST". I don't control the API implementation. All i get is an exception "task as cancelled"

Have you considered trying HttpClient.DeleteAsync

@stuartd DeleteAsync does not have an overload which would accept a request body.

@JoshHick Postman can generate C# code from a request. I would suggest to generate one and compare the headers.

this solved my issue. Sending Transfer-Encoding: chunked header. see here https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6185

Definitely there is no problem with .NET when sending and receiving data as response of DELETE methods in WebApi.
Here a working snippet that you can insert on a controller youn can create simply with dotnet new webapi.
I added a DELETE method that take an object class of type MyClass and returns the data submitted within another object.
// this is an arbitrary class to send to DELETE method
public class MyClass
{
    public string Username { get; set; }        
}
    
// this is your code but with data and internal DELETE URL to call
[HttpGet("/stackoverflow/try")]
public async Task<object> DeleteWithPostAsync()
{
    // change this accordin with your local domanin and port
    var domainAndPort = "http://localhost:1234";
    
    var client = new HttpClient();
    //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    HttpRequestMessage request = new 
        HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, 
            $"{domainAndPort}/stackoverflow/delete")
        {
            Content = new StringContent("{\"Username\": \"kiggyttass\"}", Encoding.UTF8, 
                "application/json")
        };

    var result = await 
        client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var response = await 
        result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    return response;
}

// this simulates the delete API you call 
[HttpDelete("/stackoverflow/delete")]
public object DeletionAsync([FromBody] MyClass json)
{
    var obj = new
    {
        Message = $"Hey {json.Username}! deletion operation was completed successfully",
        Details = "No problems with that"
    };
    return Ok(obj);
}


When you call the GET /stackoverflow/trymethod, it calls the DELETE method and returns the response you want. That should be like this one:
{"message":"Hey kiggyttass! deletion operation was completed successfully","details":"No problems with that"}

Hope it helps!
Cose belle!

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6185 solved my issue. Adding Transfer-Encoding: chunked header
